# Unable to run parallel tests using maven surefire plugin and EasyMock

Tags: logging, junit4, easymock, maven-surefire-plugin, parallel-testing

I've trying to run my JUnit classes in parallel, every time I run my tests I'm getting different errors. Some times a ClassA fails, some times the ClassB fails, sometimes nothing fails.

I'm using maven-surefire-plugin (version 2.19.1) and JUnit 4.8. What I noticed is the exception I'm getting is an Assertion Error from EasyMock. The problem seems to be when I have a class that creates an instance of Logger class (log4j), internally calls "RepositorySelector.getLoggerRepository()" to get the Logger given a "classname". When it runs in parallel, more than one class creates an instance of the Logger and EasyMock is detecting that "RepositorySelector.getLoggerRepository()" is being called more than the expected calls.

here an example:

```
public class ClassA{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ClassA.class);
    public void someMethod(){
        LOGGER.info("SomeMethod");
    }
}

public class ClassB{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ClassB.class);
    public void someMethodB(){
        LOGGER.info("SomeMethodB");
    }
}    

public class ClassATest{
    private ClassA classUnderTest;
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        classUnderTest = new ClassA();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod(){
        classUnderTest.someMethod();
    }
}

public class ClassBTest{
    private ClassB classUnderTest;
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        classUnderTest = new ClassB();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethodB(){
        classUnderTest.someMethodB();
    }
}
```

And I have this configuration on my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
        <!-- Parallel classes -->
        <parallel>classes</parallel>
        <threadCountClasses>2</threadCountClasses>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

To me, seems like when two tests ran at the same time, and each test executes the @Before method (setUp method) and calls the constructor of ClassA or B and it creates a new instance of the Logger class and EasyMock for some reason is trying to verify the number of times and there is where I get the Assertion Error. Is that something I'm missing? or is something that EasyMock cannot handle?

My original project has like a hundred of JUnit tests, almost all of them are logging some information. If I disabled the "parallel" option, everything works. 
Some times I got the assertion error, others I got a NullPointerException like the @Before method never gets executed and it tries to execute a @Test method and throws the NPE cause it wasn't initialized before. (That happens few times).

Any thoughts? am I missing something here?

Java version: jdk1.7.0_55
Maven: apache-maven-3.2.5
Junit: 4.8.2
Maven Surefire plugin: 2.19.1
EasyMock: 3.2  (easymockclassextension)

Answer (score 0):

If you run in parallel, your tests must agree with the Java Memory Model. That seems to be your main problem.

First, from what you are saying `RepositorySelector` is a mock that seem shared by all your tests. So it might be called twice in parallel I guess. You can set EasyMock expectations to match that (`andStubReturn` instead of `andReturn`).

Then, the NPE are probably unrelated to EasyMock. Again, I don't have enough information to be definitive on my answer but it looks like publication issues. One thread set an attribute which is not volatile so the other thread doesn't see it. I don't know if the instance creation and the `@Before` are occurring in the same thread. That can explain the problem. You can confirm that by doing `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread())` in the constructor and in the `@Before`. Or you can set everything `volatile` and it might solve your problem.

I would also suggest to update EasyMock to 3.4 and JUnit to 4.12 as there might be some concurrency fixes in both.

Finally, EasyMock supports multithreading. So there should not be any problem on that side unless there is a bug.

Comment: Thanks Henri, I'll test both approaches, I'll start first with the upgrade of the libs, and then I'll share my results!

Comment: So.. I upgraded easymock from 3.2 to 3.4, and Junit 4.8.2 to 4.12, and I got the same error.

Comment: So.. I upgraded easymock from 3.2 to 3.4, and Junit 4.8.2 to 4.12, and I got the same error. Now I'm trying logging the current thread, what I noticed is... my class ClassA or ClassB is not even created since java first instantiate the static fields (Logger) before resolving the object. And easymock is failing due to that error. That's why I got the NPE. And the @before and the constructor are running on the same thread.

Comment: Yes. Static attributes are done first. So the mock to the `RepositorySelector` should be static too.